# Print a character till end of line

Tags: linux, shell, printing, scripting, echo

I am wondering if its possible to print any character till end of line. I know its a silly to ask. 
but if its possible then this will help me to improve me the cosmetic look of my script as people use different size of putty windows.

currently I am printing "-" till EOL based on size of my window. but the size differ and "-" comes to next line on other terminals. 
like below:

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

I need this to be done in shell script. Is there any way to find the screen width and print accordingly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
cols=$(tput cols)
for ((i=0; i<cols; i++));do printf "-"; done; echo
```

Or in non-BASH use:

```
cols=`tput cols`
i=0
while [ $i -lt $cols ]; do echo -n "-"; i=`expr $i + 1`; done; echo
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
tput cols
```

to get the screen width.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `tput cols` is a reasonably standard way to get the terminal width. When you resize the terminal, a modern terminal should send a [SIGWINCH](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_478.html) that can be caught and used to redetermine the size of the terminal. Some shells have built in support for this. If you use the bash shell and have the `checkwinsize` shell option turned on, `bash` will attempt to keep the environment variables `LINES` and `COLUMNS` correct by trapping this signal.

You could even go crazy and trap SIGWINCH yourself. I found this equal parts educational and misleading:

```
trap 'tput cols' SIGWINCH
```

The above causes the shell to output the current term width not *immediately* on resize, but on the next input following a resize. I hypothesize this is not because the signal fires later, but because that's the earliest opportunity for `trap` to run the command. I think it's a shell limitation.

Comment: For me (konsole 2.11.3; bash 4.2.45; ubuntu 12.04) the output *is* immediately on resize, generally several times as the resize happens. Could be your terminal emulator.

Comment: @rici could be. Except for the experience itself, most of that last paragraph was conjecture. For the record, this is OS X Terminal Version 2.4 (326). I'm using bash 4.3.18(1)-release (built with homebrew).

Answer (score 1):

It works in zsh without the eval...

```
eval printf '=%.0s' {1..$(tput cols)}
```

- bash eval replaces $(tput cols) with the terminal column count
- bash substitutes {1..count} with space separated list of integers.
- bash printf evaluates format =%.0s upon each of its arguments.
- printf echoes the equal sign because it is not format translated
- printf % beings format secification
- printf %. beings width specification
- printf %.0 specifies zero characters wide
- printf %.0s specifies ends the width specification and says that the argument is to be treated like a string and also ends the format sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..$(tput cols)}; do echo -n '='; done
```